# UIButton position according to orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, ios5

I have create a number of buttons on an iPhone view in the following way

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

button1.frame = CGRectMake(1.0, 35.0, 100.0, 100.0);   
[button1 setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Button1", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

etc...

Because I have not used the interface builder, I am unable to control the button position upon orientation change.
Is there any way that upon I rotate iPhone, the buttons move to different coordinates?

for example if the iphone is portrait I want them to be

```
button1.frame = CGRectMake(1.0, 35.0, 100.0, 100.0);
```

if it is landscape I want them to be

```
button1.frame = CGRectMake(1.0, 105.0, 100.0, 100.0);
```

But I also want this to be dynamic, not just find the iphone orientation at the beginning. So in case I rotate the iphone after the program has load, the effect will also take place!

Thanks a lot

Comment: A couple notes. You *can* change the frame os a view created by Interface Builder just like the ones you create in code. Also I suggest you to double check if the autoresizingMask does this simple position for you. Tip: auto resizing mask is easier to understand using IB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // Set y depend on interface orientation
    CGFloat originInY = ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)  ? 105.0f : 35.0f;

    // Set the button's y offset
    button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, originInY, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
}
```

I think it'll do animation itself, if not, you can use `UIView animation`.

---

Edit for how to implement this method(just base on the code you gave):
**Note, you should set the `button1` as `instance variable` in your .h file, not `local variable` in .m file.**

.h:

```
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController
{
  UIButton * _button1;
}

// your methors

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton * button1;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@implementation MenuViewController

@synthesize button1 = _button1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  //UIButton button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  self.button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 35.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
  [self.view addSubview:button1];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation      
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // Set y depend on interface orientation
    CGFloat originInY = ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)  ? 105.0f : 35.0f;

    // Set the button's y offset
    [self.button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.button1.frame.origin.x, originInY, self.button1.frame.size.width, self.button1.frame.size.height)];
}

// other methods include dealloc.

@end
```

Comment: I think I do something wrong because I have tried a number of codes but none of them works. So here is my code, how can I implement your method?

Comment: `- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(1.0, 35.0, 100.0, 100.0);   
    [button1 setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"button1", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
}`

Comment: @user1015777 it's right. Can you show your self.view? Try to set red or blue background for self.view & button. `willRotateToInterfaceO...` is the UIViewController's `delegate`, you can just put it in your `.m` file.

Comment: No luck guys!! Here is my code in each of the two files, can you please elaborate on how to implement that method?

.m file
`#import "MenuViewController.h"
@implementation MenuViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(1.0, 35.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end`

Comment: again no luck man! :p I cannot find the mistake, I have implemented it as you stated (which actually was one of my previous trials) and again the button does not appear on the iphone! If I add the button normally, it appears, if I use any of the orientation methods it does not appear!!

Comment: I have added an NSLog in the 
`- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

And the message does not appear in the console, which means that this void is not called

Comment: @user1015777 have you `return YES` in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`? It's weird. :?

Answer (score 4):

all you would have to do would be to implement either the did rotate or the will rotate:

> Responding to View Rotation Events
>
> -willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
>
> -didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

Example:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape){
        //Behavior for landscape orientation

    }
}
```

Also be sure to also implement:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

to return `YES` for all the allowed orientations in your interface.

Comment: I have used that method but nothing happens! actually the button does not appear at all!!

Comment: @user1015777 you should `addSubview:` to the self.view for your button.

Comment: @user1015777 Try writing a `NSLog` statement in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method and in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` if you get something in the first but nothing in the second one, then the problem is in the shouldAutorotate method. Another thing, if you do not implement any of this methods what are you getting?